# Access method in class

Tags: java, android, class, methods, call

How can i call the listview method out of the FragmentTwo class? I'm using a NavDrawer which is fragment-based, so i have to initiate the ListView in the FragmentTwo class. 
This is my code:

```
    package xy;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
View rootview;
private Context context;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    return rootview;
    list.this.listview();
}
class list extends MainActivity{
        public void listview(){
            String[] listcontent = {"Test1","text2","text4"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, getView().R.layout.listviewcontent, listcontent);
            ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        public void registerClickCallback() {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    String message = "You clicked # " + position + " which is:" + textView.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(list.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }


    }
```

}

My main problem is the error message

```
    .....is not an enclosing class
```

when calling list.this.listview(); from the onCreate method.

Comment: `this` is a reference to the object for which the non-static method has been invoked. `referenceToObject.this` has no sense. You may also access this by `A.this` where `A` is the name of class, you do it when you are in the anonymous class and want to access instance of class `A` in which anonymous class is enclosed.

Comment: yep, without creatin object you cant call `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't  the right way to call methods in your `Fragment`'s parent `Activity`.

You can get the parent `Activity` with:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

And you can then access its methods in this style:

```
activity.callSomeMethodInYourActivity();
```

**Update:**

Also your `onCreateView()` throws an "unrechable statement" error because you have code after the `return` statement. This code can't be executed because the method is quit when the `return` statement is reached.

**Complete solution:**

Place this in your MainActivity.java file:

```
public void listview(){
    String[] listcontent = {"Test1","text2","text4"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, getView().R.layout.listviewcontent, listcontent);
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String message = "You clicked # " + position + " which is:" + textview.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(list.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And your fragment should look like this:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.listview()

        return rootview;
    }
}
```

After all I don't really understand why you are not placing the `listview()` and `registerClickCallback()` methods directly in your `Fragment`. IMHO this would make more sense...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm way too stupid to solve my problem. I'm getting always something like "unrechable statement"

Comment: My code now looks like this:         
list createlist = new list();
        createlist.listview();